# Can a permanent marker be used on a PCB without damaging it?

Tags: pcb, silkscreen

I need to cover up a line of text on the silkscreen of some PCBs and I'm not sure of the best way to do it. I've read that removing the printed text with a chemical will likely damage the boards, so covering it up seems like the best option.

Can something like a Sharpie permanent marker be used on a PCB's silkscreen without damaging the board?

Comment: Yes, it can be used without damaging the board.

Comment: Rubbing alcohol will take that sharpie right back off, for what its worth.

Comment: Right now I'm using a PCB where someone scribbled with a permanent marker, without any issue. So, no problems in using it :)

Comment: You could also place a sticker over the line of text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Some PCB fabs even use markers to mark good and tested boards.

Comment: Again with the uncommented downvote...

Answer (score 2):

Permanent marker ink is non-conductive and won't damage the traces or the solder mask. It can however act as etch resist, so don't use it on a board you want to etch unless this is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use it. Any marker and any color. Covering the silkscreen with any kind of label work too. I have done it many times and never ever had a problem. In my company we use a black sharpie to cover the old PCB versions and/or correct them when a new update is released but the boards keep coming with the older version silkscreen.

Answer (score 1):

To be really technically correct to the point of pedantry (or even punctiliousness) you should compare the data sheet / MSDS for the marker pen and the PCB and work out if they are compatible.

I'd be willing to take on trust that an Edding, Staedtler or Sharpie marker will probably be fine, but not any old marker pen which could have anything in the ink, from something that might damage the board over time to something that might become conductive over time.

As an example, Edding 8404 markers are specifically designed for Aerospace component marking.